# ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Tags: python

```
for report in reports:
    
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(reports_path, report))
```

The above is the code that I'm trying to perform in `jupyter Notebook` but it throws me an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-14-fccdf3c523e3>", line 3, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(reports_path, report))

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Comment: I've removed irrelevant tags. please don't include tags to gain attention, only when they're relevant to the question.

Comment: first you should format code (use special function when you edit text) and describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: maybe first display full path to file and open this file in text editor to see what you have in file - it seems you have text which is not correct xml or html.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tab on the first line of your code.
Python uses tabs to tell the structure of the program instead of other languages like Java, C#, C++, C, JavaScirpt, etc. where they use curley braces (`{}`) instead.

Comment: There is no tab in the first line.